# deriving a relative path from an absolute path with python

Tags: python, parsing, path

I'm looking to take an absolute path (C:\Data\client\vtpks\push\myfile.vtpk) and from it, create a relative path that contains the file folder and filename (push\myfile.vtpk) in python with os.

I've tried using os.path.relpath() but it prints "..\..\..\vtpks\push\myfile.vtpk"

How can I get it to print just "push\myfile.vtpk"?

```py
import os

file_dir = "C:\Data\client\vtpks\push"

for root, _, files in os.walk(file_dir):
  for file_name in files:
    if file_name.endswith(".vtpk"):

    absolute_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
    print(absolute_path) # getting "C:\Data\client\vtpks\push\myfile.vtpk" as expected

    rel_path = os.path.relpath(absolute_path)
    print(rel_path) # expecting "push\myfile.vtpk" but getting "..\..\..\vtpks\push\myfile.vtpk"
```

Comment: Can you specify what your current directory is and what your folder architecture looks like ?

Comment: cwd = "C:\Data\client\vtpks\push". That's the folder structure too, yeah?

Comment: I am trying to understand why the result you get is wrong. Here I can't really see why, because cwd and the example path you give in the question are unrelated ^^' Maybe you could create a simple repro with a comment in the code saying what you get and what you expect

Comment: What is the value of file_dir? It can't be `\path\to\my\file.vtpk` because `os.walks` takes a path, [as the documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Here's what I came up with.

```
import os

file_dir = "C:\Data\client\vtpks\push"

    for root, _, files in os.walk(file_dir):
        for file_name in files:
            if file_name.endswith(".vtpk"):
                absolute_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)

                # split absolute_path into head = "C:\Data\Asplundh\vtpks\push" and tail = "myfile.vtpk"
                head, tail = os.path.split(absolute_path)

                # split head to make folder = "push" (file folder name)
                _, folder = os.path.split(head)

                # concatenate folder and tail to make "push\file.vtpk" and change seperator to "/"
                blob_name = os.path.join(folder, tail).replace(os.path.sep, "/")

                print(blob_name) # push/myfile.vtpk
```

Answer (score -1):

You can obtain the path of your current working directory (cwd)
using the follow command

```
import os
base_dir = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

then you can concatenate

```
filename = 'your_path.txt'
os.path.join(base_dir, filename)
```